# How to add Back Button from an Activity to a Fragment

Tags: android

I'm using a fragment because I used a nav drawer menu. After I click "Category" menu it will take me to "Category" fragment and in that fragment, I have added a floating action bar that will take you to "Add category" activity.

Since fragments can't be viewed in AndroidManifest.xml file, I can't make a fragment as a parent. What I want is to add a "Back Button" from "Add category" activity, display a toast message (If sure to leave without saving changes..etc) and will go back to "Category" fragment.

I have tried using "onBackPressed()" and "getSuppoerActionBar()" that will show a toast but when running the app, the toast message will just show up in a few seconds and will go back to "Category" fragment.

Please help. Thanks! 
Here is my code.

CategoriesFragment.java

```
package com.example.devcash;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class CategoriesFragment extends Fragment {


    public CategoriesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false);

        //add floating action button
        FloatingActionButton categories_fab = view.findViewById(R.id.addcategories_fab);
        categories_fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // when add fab is pressed, go to add product activity
                Intent addprod = new Intent(getActivity(), AddCategoryActivity.class);
                startActivity(addprod);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setTitle("Categories");
    }
}
```

AddCategoryActivity.java

```
package com.example.devcash;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class AddCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_category);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Unsaved changes");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave without saving changes?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("LEAVE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                AddCategoryActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.show();


        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove below code from `onBackPressed()` as it is calling super class method and eventually destroying activity.

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

To handle toolbar back add following code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // todo: goto back activity from here
            onBackPressed();
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: The toast message now is showing, however when I select "cancel", it will go back to "Category Fragment". And "Back" button is not working also.

Comment: because in cancel you are closing the activity by calling finish();

Comment: use dialog.dismiss() to dismiss your dialog

Comment: I'm sorry about saying toast, it's alertdialog. Anyways, it worked! But doesn't fix the "Back button" issue

Answer (score 1):

Your AddCategoryActivity should be like this

```
public class AddCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_category);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        quitActivity();
    } 

    private void quitActivity() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Unsaved changes");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave without saving changes?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("LEAVE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            quitActivity();
            return true;
        } else
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. But still nothing happens when I click "Back" button in the app bar.

Comment: Sure, this is only for Back hardware button. You need this function also for back button on Toolbar?

Comment: Yes. That's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use EventBus.

```
class Activity{

  fun backToFragment(){
    EventBus.postEvent(BackToFragmentEvent())
  }
}

class HomeActivity{
  EventBus.register{
    fragmentmanager.replace(CategoriesFragment)
  }
}
```